# Sampling inspection - Joint distribution

Tags: probability, solution-verification, binomial-distribution

I am self-learning probability theory from William Feller's `Introduction to Probability theory and its applications`. I would like to ask for some help in deriving the correct solution to the below very interesting problem.

**Problem IX.12**

> Suppose that items with a probability $p$ of being acceptable are subject to inspection in such a way, that the probability of an item being inspected is $p'$. We have four classes, namely, "acceptable and inspected", "acceptable but not inspected" and so forth with probabilities $pp'$, $pq'$, $p'q$ and $qq'$. We are concerned with double Bernoulli trials. Let $N$ be the number of items passing the inspection desk (both inspected and uninspected) before the first defective is found, and let $K$ be the (undiscovered) number of defectives among them.  Find the joint distributions of $N$ and $K$, and the marginal distributions.

**Solution (My Attempt).**

We have,

\begin{array}{c|cc}
& \text{Acceptable} & \text{Defective}\\
\hline
\text{Inspected} & pp' & qp'\\
\text{Undiscovered} & pq' & qq'\\
\end{array}

The first defective item is found at trial number $(n+1)$, if the preceding $n$ items were either acceptable or uninspected.

$P\{\text{Acceptable} \cup \text{Uninspected}\} = P\{\text{Defective},\text{Inspected}\}^C = 1 - qp'$

$N$ is the waiting time to the first defective. $N$ follows a geometric distribution.

$P\{N = n\} = (1 - qp')^n qp' \tag{1}$

$K$ is the number of undiscovered defectives among these $n$ trials. So, given that we waited for time $n$ to find the first defective, the probability that the number of defectives equals $k$ is given by,

$P\{K = k \vert N = n\} = {n \choose k} (qq')^k p^{n-k}$

Thus, the joint distribution

\begin{align*}
P\{K = k, N = N\} &= P \{K = k \vert N =n \} \cdot P \{N = n\}\\
&= {n \choose k} (qq')^k p^{n-k} (1 - qp')^n qp'
\end{align*}

However, the textbook states the expression for the joint distribution as,

$$
P\{K = k, N = n\} ={n \choose k}(qq')^k p^{n-k} qp'
$$

Also, how to sum over all $n$ to derive an expression for the marginal distribution of $N$?

Comment: No offense but what's up with that you're still in pre-measure theory probability? I figured you'd be in measure theory probability by now

Comment: Well it seems you kind of already are in stochastic calculus... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3677363/question-on-proof-of-jensens-inequality-e-phix-ge-phiex-where

Comment: But idk this new question you're asking seems like elementary probability

Comment: @BCLC, hi! You are right, ending up learning analysis & pre-measure theory probability in a somewhat spiral way. Briefly: I moved countries, learnt some computational math - ODEs, vector calculus & algebra, and now I'm liking the theoretical side of things. Certainly, feel more matured to handle to content.

Comment: ayt i think you can kinda move on to measure theory and then measure-theoretic probability and then stochastic calculus. not sure much point for you to dwell on this elementary probability stuff. but anyhoo. good job. good for you man. merry christmas, and happy holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the joint distribution note that

$$P(n,k)=P(\text{k defects over n trials})P(\text{k not detected})P(\text{defect detected at n+1})$$

$$={n \choose k}p^{n-k}q^k \times (q')^k\times q p' $$

$$={n \choose k}p^{n-k}\times (qq')^k\times q p' $$